# Displaying a syncfusion chart in a <stacklayout> doesn't seem to work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have this XAML:

```
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding ThemeBackgroundColor}">
            <chart:SfChart>
                <chart:SfChart.Title>
                    <chart:ChartTitle Text="Scores" />
                </chart:SfChart.Title>
                <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                    <chart:CategoryAxis>
                        <chart:CategoryAxis>
                        </chart:CategoryAxis>
                    </chart:CategoryAxis>
                </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                    <chart:NumericalAxis>
                        <chart:NumericalAxis>
                        </chart:NumericalAxis>
                    </chart:NumericalAxis>
                </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
            </chart:SfChart>
    </StackLayout>
```

In a `<TableView><TableSection><ViewCell>` my chart appears but when I put it into a `<stacklayout>` like in the above then I can no longer see a chart.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Comment: it probably cannot measure the size of the chart. Try <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin, sometimes the custom controls will not render in view if we adapt the custom control inside a StackLayout. However, it can be solved by setting VerticalOptions and HorizontalOptions as "FillAndExpand" for both the StackLayout and Chart control.

```
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{Binding ThemeBackgroundColor}">
            <chart:SfChart VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                <chart:SfChart.Title>
                    <chart:ChartTitle Text="Scores" />
                </chart:SfChart.Title>
                <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                    <chart:CategoryAxis>
                        <chart:CategoryAxis>
                        </chart:CategoryAxis>
                    </chart:CategoryAxis>
                </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                    <chart:NumericalAxis>
                        <chart:NumericalAxis>
                        </chart:NumericalAxis>
                    </chart:NumericalAxis>
                </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
            </chart:SfChart>
    </StackLayout>
```